# Ingress data in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

We run Apache Storm to fetch and process data from multiple HTTP streaming APIs. This produces roughly 250 items per second that we would like to send to Elasticsearch. Each record is 250KB in size. What is the best practice to send these data to Elasticsearch?

For example, should we insert them in Elasticsearch using batches, e.g., writing them to file and use Logstash to load and process these items?

Or perhaps use Apache Kafka as an intermediate?

Or can we simply use one bolt that keeps an HTTP connection alive, and use this to load the items into Elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0):

Again it depends on your choice and people tend to use all the approaches which you list and every approaches has some benefits and some drawback and you need to choose the one which suits your requirement best.

At a very high-level i'll try to mention the most important aspect of them.

**Logstash**

1. If you need some sort of filtering, conversion you can use logstash and use the [GROK filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html).
2. Requires another infra and maintenance for logstash.

**Kafka**

1. Can provide better fault-tolerance and queuing mechanism when ES is down or having performance issues.
2. Another infra and not in ELK stack, like logstash.

**Direct ES ingest using bulk API**

1. Simple to use, without any extra configuration and maintenance if you have good fault-tolerance and retry mechanism at client side.

**According to information you provided, it doesn't seem to be very frequency, low latency system and IMHO you can simply go ahead with option 3 ie direct ingest in ES using bulk API.**